# mongodb: $orderBy on a field in the first element of a list contained in each document

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I have a collection in which element has a list of objects. I would like to use `$orderBy` on a specific field on the first element of a list of objects that each document has.

For example:
each document represents a user, and each user has a list of sessions. I would like to sort the users on the date stored in the first session of the list.

Maybe something like `{ $orderby: { "sessions[0].timestamp" : 1 } }` ?

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you expand on your question with an example of exactly what you mean please?

Comment: done: each document represents a user, and each user has a list of sessions. I would like to sort the users on the date stored in the first session of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operation you ask for is a simple one with `.sort()`. Perhaps you are not aware of the usage of "dot notation" with MongoDB

With the following documents as a minimal example:

```js
{ 
    "name" : "Fred", 
    "sessions" : [ { "timestamp" : ISODate("2014-06-05T10:38:24.371Z") } ]
}
{ 
    "name" : "Barney",
    "sessions" : [ { "timestamp" : ISODate("2014-06-05T10:38:34.557Z") } ]
}
```

Issue the following query:

```js
db.users.find({},{ _id: 0}).sort({ "sessions.0.timestamp": -1 })
```

And get the ordered result by the first item of the array, timestamp field:

```js
{
    "name" : "Barney",
    "sessions" : [ { "timestamp" : ISODate("2014-06-05T10:38:34.557Z") } ]
}

{ 
    "name" : "Fred", 
    "sessions" : [ { "timestamp" : ISODate("2014-06-05T10:38:24.371Z") } ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It actually solves my problem. Actually, I have another question: does the "dot notation" include operations like count? In other words, if I would like to sort the users by number of sessions, how would I do?

Comment: @francescostablum If you have another question then feel free to post another question on stack exchange. Someone will undoubtedly answer it for you. It may even be considered a question worthy of voting up